# Displaying only selected categories

Tags: categories

I am trying to show only selected categories (or taxomony) from the dropdown, right now my code jumps off to another page of the selected category. How Can i do that?

```
$option ;
$categories = get_categories(); 
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $option .= '<option value="'.get_option('home').'/category/'.$category->slug.'">';
    $option .= $category->cat_name;
    //$option .= ' ('.$category->category_count.')';
    $option .= '</option>';
}
echo $option;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `get_term_link(  $category->slug,'category' )` to get the category url refer 
[link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/)